# WCF and nullable types supported?

Tags: wcf, nullable

I have a Composite type DataContact and one of the DataMember is a decimal? return type

```
[DataMember]
public decimal? ExchangeRate { get; set; }
```

When a value is assigned to the ExchangeRate property from the client, the serialized value across the wire at the service end is null. Why is this happening as WCF 4.5 fully supports Nullable types according to MSDN. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your assignment of ExchangeRate? Is the client proxy generated or are you creating a channel manually?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not already, I suggest you enable WCF tracing on the client and service, so you have a better understanding of the serialized values. At least you could confirm the client parameter values and serialization and then compare to the result received by the WCF Service.

For reference: WCF tracing provides diagnostic data for fault monitoring and analysis. You can use tracing instead of a debugger to understand how an application is behaving, or why it faults.[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)